# Grid not binding json data - MVC Kendo UI Grid bound via Ajax to a WebAPI and OpenAccess ORM

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Below is a sample of MVC Kendo UI Grid bound via Ajax to a WebAPI. The WebAPI uses OpenAccess ORM as data model.
The below code loads the grid with the auto generated columns as per the model and the WebAPI is called successfully and data returned in JSON as given below.

The issue seems to be in grid data binding. The data is not visible in the grid but the columns are loaded successfully. What is missing in the MVC code?

### JSON Data:

[{"DC_ID":51234,"DATAACCESS_ID":79238,"MASTERDATA_FLG":"Y","INPUT_TYPE_CD":"QRY","FILE_PATH":"D:\","DESCR":"AAA DATA CAPTURE","STATUS":"A","CREATED_BY":"SYSTEM","CREATED_DTTM":"01-JAN-2013"},{"DC_ID":79238,"DATAACCESS_ID":79238,"MASTERDATA_FLG":"Y","INPUT_TYPE_CD":"QRY","FILE_PATH":"D:\","DESCR":"TEST DATA CAPTURE","STATUS":"A","CREATED_BY":"SYSTEM","CREATED_DTTM":"01-JAN-2013"}]

### MVC code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<eConverge.DomainModel.Datacapture>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.AutoGenerate(true);
      })
      .ToolBar(tools =>
      {
          tools.Create();
      })
      //.Sortable()
      //.Pageable()
      //.Filterable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.DC_ID);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Url("http://localhost/econ/econ.webapi/api/datacaptures").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Create(create => create.Url("http://localhost/econ/econ.webapi/api/datacaptures").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
            .Update(update => update.Url("http://localhost/econ/econ.webapi/api/datacaptures").Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url("http://localhost/econ/econ.webapi/api/datacaptures").Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))      
      )
)
```

Comment: is there some error message you're getting?

Comment: No error when I view it in Chrome Inspect. Infact, I got the JSON data back (posted above). No javascript errors in kendo grid. If I use a grid using javascript only (without mvc wrappers) it shows the data. The issue with building the grid with javascript is support for the datamodel. So I prefer the mvc wrappers/helpers (not sure what its called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some more code required to bind the grid to Web API controller. I recommend checking the following resources:

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-11-29/the_facts_on_using_kendo_ui_with_asp_net_webapi.aspx

http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/binding-to-a-web-apicontroller.aspx

Comment: Thanks for links. I have seen them already and still trying to figure out what is missing. I see in the "the facts..." link there is a suggestion to add "DataSourceRequest ". I feel DataSourceRequest is not required because at the moment I am not adding Sorting, filtering, paging, skip, etc.

Comment: Thanks for links. I have seen them already and still trying to figure out what is missing. I see in the "the facts..." link there is a suggestion to add "DataSourceRequest ". I feel DataSourceRequest is not required because at the moment I am not adding Sorting, filtering, paging, skip, etc. The other suggestion is to enable Full OData support in WebAPI and this I believe also is only required for sorting, paging, etc. For basic functionality of just displaying the data rows, I support these 2 are not required. I'll keep digging and welcome suggestions and comments.

Comment: If you check the second link (the code library project) you would see what the difference is. A hint - DataSourceRequest **is** required.

Comment: Thanks Atanas. That resolved the issue. Looks like the json msg returned was not interpreted by kendoui grid. After adding DataSourceRequest, the json returned that kendoui grid understands was modified to start with "{"Data":...."

Comment: I am having a similar issue, can you post your code as to how you solved this please?